# Ruby on Rails: Dropdown menu options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, drop-down-menu

I have an app where the user can select a technology from a dropdown menu. I want to code in the most common options, as well as show the technologies in the database.

Is it possible to have predetermined options as well as the options in the tech column in one drop down menu? Something like this?

```
<%= f.select( :tech, [['Tech1'],['Tech2'],['Tech3'], ['Tech4'],  Project.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq], :prompt => "Select a previous Technology") %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add arrays to concatenate them:

```
basic_techs = [['Tech1'],['Tech2'],['Tech3'], ['Tech4']]
db_techs = Project.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq
<%= f.select( :tech, basic_techs + db_techs, :prompt => "Select a previous Technology") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all the `Project` items, building them just for getting the `tech` column is extremely overkill.

```
db_techs = Project.select("projects.tech").uniq.map {|p| [p.tech]}
```

(this will generate a `SELECT DISTINCT projects.tech` query, instead of `SELECT * FROM projects`)

Also, you don't want the basic_techs to show up twice in the list, so

```
all_techs = basic_techs + db_techs
all_techs.uniq!
```